# TYPO3 v10: Remove <p> tags around paragraphs in custom RTE field (CKeditor)

Tags: ckeditor, typo3, typoscript, rte, typo3-10.x

I have a RTE field in my custom extension for TYPO3 10.4 with Fluid Styled Content. The RTE CKEditor automatically wraps each paragraph with a p tag. I'd like to get rid of this `p` tag. It's just a teaser field where I don't need line breaks or paragraphs.

What I tried so far is to create my own `parseFunc` via TypoScript to solve the problem during frontend output:

```
lib.parseFunc_my_teaser < lib.parseFunc_RTE
lib.parseFunc_my_teaser.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines >
lib.parseFunc_my_teaser.nonTypoTagStdWrap.encapsLines {
  encapsTagList = p
  remapTag.P =
}
```

In my Fluid template I use the parsefunc like this:

```
{article.data.teaser -> f:format.html(parseFuncTSPath: 'lib.parseFunc_my_teaser')}
```

This works and `p` tags are gone.

But I wonder if there is no nicer solution. I think I need to find a solution to tackle this problem either within the CKEditor configuration or via Page TSconfig. Unfortunately I wasn't able to find a proper approach.

By the way, another problem is, that in the "Info" Backend module of TYPO3 in my installation the view for Page TSconfig filtered by `RTE.` is empty. Any ideas on this?

[image: TPYO3 v10 Backend Module "Info" with empty Page TSconfig view]

Comment: Especially for such short text fields with very limited format options, maybe https://docs.typo3.org/other/typo3/view-helper-reference/master/en-us/typo3/fluid/latest/Format/StripTags.html could be a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I actually do that directly within an own RTE preset for CKE4 (tested in TYPO3 8, 9, 10 LTS):

```
editor.config.format_tags: "p"
editor.config.enterMode: 2
editor.config.shiftEnterMode: 2
```

With that an editor can't write P-tags. Even not in Source-Mode of CKE4.

Comment: where to put this?

Comment: @Andrea_86 if you take a look into https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/10.4/en-us/Configuration/BestPractices.html#config-best-practices and https://docs.typo3.org/c/typo3/cms-rte-ckeditor/10.4/en-us/Configuration/Concepts.html#config-concepts you get a good overview. tl;dr: you can add this in your own yaml configuration file OR (something I didn't used ever) overwrite configs with PageTSconfig.

Comment: Additionally i added following line in the RTE Preset yaml file
processing.overruleMode: nothing
This blocks wrapping p tags